# typescript express failed to export and show undefined when running by nodeJS through required require('./main.ts')

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

My problem is difficult to explain, so i simply the code. let me post the code first

main.ts

```
import express from 'express';
let a = 1 
console.log ('a in main.ts', a)
export let b = a 
const app = express()
let PORT = 8080
import {c} from "./efg"
console.log("export from efg.ts", c)
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server runs at ${PORT}`);
  });
```

efg.ts

```
import {b} from './main'
console.log('export from main.ts', b) 
export let c = 'efg'
```

main.js

```
require('ts-node/register')
require('./main.ts')
```

when i run the code with ts-node main.ts, everything is fine, it prints out

```
a in main.ts 1
export from main.ts 1
export from efg.ts efg
Server runs at 8080
```

but when i run the code with node main.js , strange things happen

```
a in main.ts 1
export from main.ts undefined <---- main.ts export become undefined
export from efg.ts efg
Server runs at 8080
```

the strange thing is if I rename main.js to other names like run.js, it works normally
Can anyone tell me why this happens? I don't understand why when i use the name main.js the export from main.ts become undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have a `main.js` importing your `main.ts` file but instead have a [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) file at the root of your project and then compile using `tsc`, you will then be able to enter the following command `node main.js`.